# Use value returned from cURL to make a subsequent call as an Authorization header

Tags: php-curl

I am making a call to an api with cURL and I get a successful call but the api requires that I use the successful call to make subsequent calls, specifically: use the value returned to make the subsequent call as an Authorization header.

I am not sure what exactly to try. I am getting the correct response in the body of the page, just through curl_exec($ch); but i'm not sure where to proceed.

```
<?php

//Set Variables
$username = 'my_username';
$password = 'my_password';
$showcode = 'my_showcode';

//Set url variable with showcode as a query string
$url = "https://api.mysstaging.com/mysRest/v2/Authorize/?showCode=$showcode";

// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

//Set un/pw for basic auth
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

//Expect to store and use variable but not sure how
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Authorization: ' . mysGUID,
));


// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

From curl_exec($ch), I get a response in the body with mysGUID, and this is where I think I should/can pass it as a variable but i'm not sure how to store the response as a variable in php and then make a subsequent call using it? I apologize I am still pretty green with API's but hopefully I am on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sort this out. In case anyone else is stuck the approach I took was to set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER so I could utilize the values. Then I created a variable for returned key and value (I am calling this the GUID). I then used this variable to convert the output to an array which then allowed me to get just the value from the returned GUID, which I then stored in a variable I can use for subsequent calls.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// create variable for authorization output, this gives us the GUID we need.
$authOutput = curl_exec($ch);

// Convert JSON string to Array to pull the GUID value only
$outputArray = json_decode($authOutput, true);

//create variable for myResult variable
$myResult= $outputArray[0]["myResult"];

echo "My Result = $myResult";

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```